# Open-source list of whitelisted URL domain names?

Tags: url, dns, whitelist, blacklist

Is there a source or set of sources from which I may obtain a list of whitelisted URL domain names? I'm looking for something on the order of millions of URLs, rather than hundreds or thousands. Whitelist based on either lack of observed malicious activity associated with the domain or proven that 100% of traffic from this domain is nonmalicious.

Comment: whitelisted based on what?

Comment: "Is there a source or set of sources from which I may obtain a list of whitelisted URL domain names? " Simple answer: no. Also what is "URL domain name"? "Whitelist based on either lack of observed malicious activity associated with the domain" online gambling is allowed in some parts of the world, and not in other. So it is malicious or not? "proven that 100% of traffic from this domain is nonmalicious. " A negative proof is impossible. Domain names switch hands too. I do not know what is your real problem you want to solve, but you seem starting on a wrong path.